# Unable to install a fresh version of MySQL on CentOS

Tags: centos, mysql

These are the steps, that I followed:

1. `cd /etc/yum.repos.d` # go to repositories
2. `rpm -qf mysql-community.repo` # get the name of old repositories to delete
3. `yum remove mysql57-community-release` # it is 5.7, but I was unable to install it
4. `wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm` # download it again for my Centos 6.6
5. `yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm` # install it
6. `yum repolist enabled | grep "mysql.*-community.*"` # check that we have fresh versions, yes it's ok, I see mysql57-community
7. `yum install mysql-community-server`

The last step does not work. When I run this command, I see that for some incredibly insane reason CentOS tries to install `mysql57-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm` which is of course not compatible with CentOS 6.6. and therefore installation procedure fails. Why is that? Why does it take incorrect version, that I've not even downloaded??? And how to fix it? Thanks!!

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Show the complete output.

Comment: It is impossible, because I do it on a remote server through ssh and the console language is not English

Comment: If you could suggest how I can switch language to English and copy console output to some text file that would be great

Comment: What are you talking about? Just paste it in your question.

Comment: Just copy and paste the text, the image is unreadable.

Comment: Please, have a look. I updated my question. On the image you can see many times `el7.x86_64`, but I did not know even about its existance. The previous version on my CentOS 6.6. was 5.1.X. and I downloaded 5.7 el6.x86_64. So I wonder why it takes some incorrect package and tries to install it

Comment: It's a problem to copy paste text. I run these commands on a remote server through ssh, I do not have access through any gui and I do not know hove to move text around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the problem:

You replaced the mysql57-community repo for EL7 with the one for EL6, but yum still has cached metadata for the EL7 repo. Try clearing the metadata:

```
yum clean metadata
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! Now I see that it works. You need to be a real guru to know all such secret mantras! Thanks!